# javascript two "?" operators one by one

Tags: javascript

Help me please understand how this piece of code are working.

```
function getOpacity( elem ) {
var filter = elem.style.filter;
return filter ?
      filter.indexOf("opacity=") >= 0 ?
        (parseFloat(filter.match(/opacity=([^)]+)/)[1]) / 100) + "" :
     "" :
      elem.style.opacity;
 }
```

I was try console.log(filter) and received empty string. I thing something interesting going on with two "?" operators. I know for what there is one "?". But i need help with two such operators.

Comment: There is nothing special about two conditional operators, they are just nested. The same way you can do `a + (b + c)` you can do `a ? (x ? y : z) : c`. Each operand can be *any* expression, so you can use the conditional operator as one of the operands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just nested conditional (i.e. `?:`) operators. This code is equivalent to:

```
if (filter) {
    if (filter.indexOf("opacity=") >= 0) {
        return (parseFloat(filter.match(/opacity=([^)]+)/)[1]) / 100) + "";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
} else {
    return elem.style.opacity;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `:` instead of actual javascript to show the equivalent?

Comment: @jfriend00 Oops, thought this was python for a second. I'll fix that. (which is especially strange because python doesn't have the conditional operator...)

Answer (score 1):

The default precedence for

```
a ? b : c ? d : e
```

is

```
a ? b : (c ? d : e)
```

and not, for example

```
(a ? b : c) ? d : e
```

This makes it easy to use the `?` ternary operator much like a series of `if/then/else` statements without superfluous parentheses, although you're welcome to add them if you think they improve readability.

Comment: I can't say I've ever run into a case where I actively thought *any* nesting of `?:` led to more readable code.. well, +1 for pointing out the precedence.